# Android GCM Push notifications not received on some latest OS (Oreo and Pie)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, android-push-notification

We're using GCM for push notification for our app with target release to 26. But on some devices  with OS(Oreo and Pie) notifications are not received. We have implemented push notification channels as well.For mostly users it worked but some users face this issue.

Details:

- Play services GCM version: 11.0.4
- compileSdkVersion 26
- targetSdkVersion 26

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52943903/7666442

Comment: Any reason you're not on FCM yet?

Comment: @AL. Do you think FCM is a solution of this problem?

Comment: GCM has been deprecated for quite sometime now. At this point (IMO), using it today will have unpredictable behavior. FCM is the newer version, which contains improvements (and under the hood bug fixes) which may or may not *fix* (if there is an actual issue) your problem. Furthermore, GCM will be totally discontinued this year, so even if you still choose to go with GCM, you will be forced to migrate to FCM soon enough.

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217859/heads-up-push-notification-not-doing-the-pop-up-function